# Fast streaming to framebuffer

Tags: stream, framebuffer, xorg

What is the most best method to write a stream/array of raw RGB pixels (format as required by Xorg) to a window of fixed size? No synchronisation is required, nor are there any timing requirements, just minimal average CPU usage.

Is it necessary to copy the data to a memory location managed by Xorg
or can one pass just a pointer?
If it is necessary to perform a full copy of the data, is there also a portable way (Linux only, but portable between Intel, Nvidia and AMD) of doing this with GPU hardware acceleration?

How to write existing data to the screen in a fast way?

```
struct {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
} pixel_t; //other format/padding also possible, if required

struct {
  pixel_t[WIDTH*HEIGHT] data;
} frame_t;

frame_t* frame = get_next_frame_from_stream(); //<= already optimized
set_as_xorg_framebuffer(frame); //<= I'm searching for this
```